# Selecting Multiple Columns to hide at once

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a report in which has multiple columns that compares numbers throughout the fiscal year. For example, July to August, August to September, etc. Unfortunately, when I do this manually, I have to unhide all columns and rehide columns not used to complete. I am automating this report. At this moment, I have all of the columns visible. Due to being in middle of the fiscal year, my report will have columns on both the left and right sides of the needed data. I am trying to have these unneeded columns hidden.

I have created a reference row (row 1) with JAN, FEB, MAR, etc for reference purposes only for my code as I have created a userform that detects these entries.

For the data I need this month, I have selected the referenced cell and offset it by one to get the first column selected that I will need hidden. How would I select all of the columns from my selected column to the column A in my script? Below is the code of where I am:

```
With Worksheets("ACD")
 For counter = 1 To 200
    Set curcell = Worksheets("ACD").Cells(1, counter)
    If curcell.Value = FormMonth Then
    curcell.Offset(0, -1).EntireColumn.Select
    End If
  Next counter
End With
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example on how to hide multiple columns, based on your situation:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideMonthColumns()
    Dim workingDate As Date                      'filled in from your form?
    workingDate = #10/1/2018#                    'set for testing here

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ACD")

    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim workingCol As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With ws
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = 1 To lastCol
            If .Cells(1, i) = workingDate Then
                workingCol = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        '--- hide all the columns to the left and right of the working column
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, workingCol - 1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        '--- ... and hide all the columns to the right, checking for the edge
        If (workingCol + 9) < lastCol Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, workingCol + 9), _
                   .Cells(1, lastCol)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the assist! The script hides the columns to the left beautifully, however it does not seem to be hiding the columns to the right as needed. Would this have something to do with lastCol using xlToLeft in the With Statement? Also, I will have the active column plus 9 additional columns of information to the right that I will need to keep visible. Everything to the right of these 10 columns will need to be hidden. I changed the (workingCol +1) to (workingCol +9). I tried both, however neither will hide the columns to the right. Thanks!

Comment: I made a slight update to the answer above, to check if your nine columns are at the far right of your data. But I can tell you that the code above is hiding everything to the left and right of the nine columns for me.

Comment: thanks again! You've been a major help and the code is up and running. I don't know why, however the script did not work on my end. Hiding to the right only selected the data I was wanting to keep. I was able to make some adjustments and get it to where I need it to be (for hiding data on the right):                        
        Sheets("ACD").Cells(workingcol).Offset(0, 9).Select
        Selection.range(.Cells(1, Selection + 1), .Cells(1, lastcol)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With              Thanks again!!